# How to create and use dll files in C#

Tags: c++, dll, load, dllimport

I am currently trying to learn how to write and use .dll files for Windows in C# and C++. I think once I understand one of those langueages I will be able to figure out the other one quite easily. I have searched for over 5 hours today but have had no luck in finding a working .dll guide. They are either outdated and refuse to work with my compiler or simply are downright trash. Does anybody know a *good* guide that *works*? I am using Dev C++ and VC++ 2010. Thanks for helping me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLL's in C# are dead easy.

1. Create a new project that builds to a dll.
2. Add a reference to the new dll project to your existing project.
3. Use classes marked public in your dll as if they were part of your original project.

Peachykeen has laid out the most basic way to export classes and functions from a C++ DLL. There is a more advanced technique that I would suggest. Instead of exporting each class you need, derive all of your classes in the dll from interfaces (class with at least one pure virtual method). Then export a factory function(s) that returns pointers to these interfaces. This reduces the coupling between your main executable and the dll, since you only need to share interfaces, not any implementation details.

Code project has a good article on this technique.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/howto_export_cpp_classes.aspx

One nice benefit of the approach above is that it drastically reduces compile times. You can completely reimplement a DLL without needing to recompile the main application.

Comment: Using virtual functions and factories can work, it may be easier to work with than exports but I think it's slightly more complex to set up. Just different styles, really, and both work fine.

Answer (score 5):

DLLs in C# and C++ are somewhat different, especially in how they're used. C# uses assemblies, with all sorts of metadata packed in, and hides most of the details. C++ does not, you have to tell it what is exported and how.

Making DLLs generally consists of writing your code, then for each class or function you want to use (from outside the DLL), add this bit:

```
int __declspec(dllexport) function(int param);
class __declspec(dllexport) object;
```

That will "export" the symbols, making them visible from outside the DLL. You only need to do this for ones that will be used externally, and for classes, only on the class (not each method).

When using the DLL, you'll want to include a header that has all functions, but with `__declspec(dllimport)` notes. This will tell your code these are used from an external DLL. You need to provide the lib (created when you compiled the DLL) to the linker as an input file, and everything should line up.

An easy way to handle that is:

```
#ifndef IMPORT_MYLIB
#    define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

int MYLIB_API function();
```

When using the DLL in another app, simply `#define IMPORT_MYLIB` and the header will be set up appropriately.

For C#, you need to simply create a library with public classes, then add it as a reference to the other project. You can then use classes from it and the two files will automatically be linked together (much simpler, but not always as clean as C++'s method).

Note that DLLs are Microsoft-specific, and there are quite a few little details that may interest you later on (how imports are searched for and such).

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio they're now called "assemblies" instead of DLL's. The change in terminology is confusing. Creating a DLL consists of just creating a project of the right type and adding your code. Consuming a DLL from a different language or compiler can be tricky though.

Did you try [this](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mahesh/pr1202172006014101AM/pr12.aspx) tutorial?

Comment: Why the downvotes? The answer is incomplete because it does not address C++, but the C# side is correct and the link is relevant.